# Date attribute not working in method of a class java

Tags: java, date, attributes

This is the attributes of the class customer.

```
public class Customer {
private String customer_username;
private String customer_password;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Date dateOfBirth;
private String address;
private String postcode;
private String email;
(...)
```

This is a method that saves to a txt file, 
it has an error for Date dateOfBirth, I dont know what to include to make it work

```
public void saveToFile(){
    FileWriter out = null;
    try{
        out = new FileWriter("CustomerDetails.txt", true);
        out.append("Customer Username:   ");
        out.append(customer_username);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Customer Password:   ");
        out.append(customer_password);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Name:   ");
        out.append(name);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Surname:   ");
        out.append(surname);         
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        **out.append("Date of Birth:   ");**
        **out.append(dateOfBirth);**
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Address:   ");
        out.append(address);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Postcode:   ");
        out.append(postcode);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("Email:   ");
        out.append(email);
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append("**********************************");
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException ioe){  
}
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433198/serializing-java-util-date

Answer (score 1):

try

```
out.append(dateOfBirth.toString());
```

If you don't like the format, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to change it. (see the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Answer (score 0):

Your dateOfBirth is an object of type Date, you can not print it in a standart syso.

I you want to print the date use: `dateOfBirth.toString());`