# Read a java.sql.Timestamp object from ObjectStream without altering the time value?

Tags: java

I have a `ObjectInputStream` which has a `java.sql.Timestamp` object. I want to read the actual value that was sent, without the effect of timezone. (client is in a different timezone from server).

How do I do that?

```
// ois is an objectinputstream 
Object obj = ois.readObject();
```

Even `obj.toString()` returns a changed 'time'. I cannot get the timezone info of the inputstream.

`java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Date` does not get affected. Only timestamp is the problem.

Suppose the client send the inputstream from EST and the time is 6:00 pm, when I receive it in PST that `6:00 pm` is converted to `3:00 pm`. I don't want that. I want to read the `6:00 pm` directly.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the `Timestamp` and writes it to `ObjectOutputStream`? Can you also post the desired result and the actual result?

Comment: Just cast it to `Timestamp`, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @user207421 But still I cannot get the timezone it is coming from. So I want the original value, so that I don't have to change it any way.

Comment: I don't believe the timezone is changed. I believe the problem here is `toString()` formatting it in the current timezone.Try formatting it with `DateFormatter` in its own timezone.

Comment: @user207421 I won't have the origin timezone i.e. the client timezone.

Comment: I am suggesting that it is in the timestamp object.

Comment: @user207421 `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date` does not have timezone information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the "original" timezone because it was never part of the `java.sql.Timestamp` object. When a `java.sql.Timestamp` object gets serialized only the internal `nanos` field of that objects gets serialized (not counting the information of the base class `java.util.Date`), as mention in the [Serialized Form from `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.sql.Timestamp):

> *Class `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `Date` implements Serializable*
>
> **serialVersionUID**: 2745179027874758501L
>
> ### Serialized Fields
>
> **nanos**
>
> int nanos

When you deserialize this object again you get a `java.sql.Timestamp` object with the internal `nanos` field set to the exact value as before. In both cases both objects reference the same point in time by the unix timestamp. It doesn't matter if it is 6:00 pm EST or 3:00 pm PST, it's the same point in time.

Depending on your requirement you might want to send a different value if you are interested in the local client time.

Comment: It is the same. But the requirement is to save 6:00 pm in the database. I am trying to get that.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee You can send a different value, or some additional meta information about the timezone the client is using.

Comment: I don't have access to the client api.

Comment: The timezone is in the `Date`.

Comment: @user207421 It looks like that `java.util.Date` does not serialize the timezone information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4433282/286934.